# doubts about incrementation of array pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Here I'm getting the output 'bcde' but since 'a' is a constant array pointer it should not have been incremented inside `fun()` right?  Then why is it allowed here?

```
    void fun(char a[])
    {
     a++;
     printf("%s",a);
    }

    void main()
    {
     char a[]="abcde";
     fun(a);
    }
```

Comment: Aside: It's `int main`, always.

Comment: You _claim_ `a` is a constant array pointer, but you have two `a` variables: neither is a constant pointer nor pointer to constant.  In fact, one isn't even a pointer!

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is array decaying?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

Answer (score 3):

When you pass an array to a function in C, the array "decays" to a pointer. In other words, an equivalent function can be declared like this:

```
void fun(char *a)
```

Now the code inside the function makes perfect sense: the pointer is incremented, so when the result is passed to `printf`, the original string is printed starting with the second letter.

Comment: @user3801801 The pointer is not constant. Moreover, the memory the pointer points to is perfectly modifiable, because you wrote `char a[]="abcde"`, not `char *a="abcde"`. But even a pointer to constant can be modified (as opposed to a constant pointer, which is declared differently).

Comment: No, not a constant pointer. A pointer to constant data is not the same as a constant pointer. Also, what user3801801 said is correct. The data isn't even constant.

Comment: okay...and if it was declared char *s="abcde" inside main den it still remains the same ryt?

Comment: @user3801801 Yes, the code and its behavior would remain the same.

Comment: In C,if i declare char *s="abcde" then content of s(i.e.*s='o';) is not allowed ryt?den y is it allowed in C++?

Comment: @user3801801 The assignment is not allowed in both C and in C++. The difference is that in C the code will compile, while in C++ the compiler is going to complain about the assignment of a string literal to a non-const pointer (C++ requires `const char *s = "abcd"`)

Answer (score 2):

When you pass an array name to your function then you are passing pointer to its first element.

```
void fun(char a[])  // a is not an array of char
```

is equivalent to

```
void fun(char *a)
```

You can modify `a` inside function because it is not an array name but a pointer to `char`.
You can't modify `a` in `main` as it is declared as array. Array names are non modifiable l-values.

Answer (score 1):

When you are in function arguments, `char a[]` is treated exactly as if you wrote `char *a`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no any "constant array pointer"

In this statement

```
char a[]="abcde";
```

there is declared a non-const array. You may change it for example as

```
a[0] = 'A';
```

When you pass the array to the function as an argument then there is used conversion from the array to a pointer of type `char *` that points to the first element of the array.

This function declaration

```
void fun(char a[]);
```

is equivalent to

```
void fun(char *a);
```

The parameter is adjaced to the pointer.

So inside the function you can to change the pointer itself and the object it points to. For example

```
 a++;
 *a = 'B';
```

If you want that the pointer would not be changed in the function you could declare it as

```
void fun(char * const a);
```

In this case the compiler would issue an error for statement

```
 a++;
```

because a is indeed a const pointer.